# jQuery - Call function when dropping div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run function `insertHouse()` when dropping div#Draggable. I can't manage to make it work. You can see me trying to call it in the second line from the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

```
<img src="images/door1.jpg" id="draggable">
<div id="items"></div>

// Place house;
function insertHouse()
{
blablabla
}

$( init );

function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
  $('body').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );
}

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  function insertHouse();
}
```

Comment: `function insertHouse();` is a syntax error. Remove `function` and/or set `insertHouse` directly as drop handler: `drop: insertHouse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will work...

```
function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
  $('body').droppable( {
drop: function(event, ui){
insertHouse();
}
  } );
}
```

Comment: your code should work too just change the call from `function insertHouse()` to `insertHouse()`